# Какова функция союза "НЕ ТО ЧТО"?

Tags: синтаксис, союзы

В чем функция союза "НЕ ТО ЧТО" в нижеуказанных предложениях?

1. Василий очень аккуратный водитель, **не то что** его друг Сергей.
2. Он не даст и копейки, **не то что** рубля.
3. У соседа машина не ухоженная, **не то что** наша.